# Run Flutter socket io even if app is closed

Tags: flutter, dart

**Issue** : I am using socket_io_client plugin to build socket services. I am using flutter background service as mentioned in flutter website but it is not working perfectly. I used background_fech but it is consuming battery very heavily. Please suggest me something so that i can integrate in a better way.

**Problem** : I am receiving socket request from backend. It is working perfectly when app is running. But I am not able to listen request if app is closed.